# How to replace two lines in an xml file using PowerShell via regex

Tags: regex, powershell

As part of a larger PowerShell Script, I'm trying to replace two lines within an xml file:

```
<!--Some description text here-->
<Variable></Variable>
```

I've been able to replace the text when it's on a single line however I've not been able to find a way to remove new lines from the file.

The obvious thought would be to try to use \r\n but this doesn't work eg:

```
$XML = Get-Content "Config.xml"
$Pattern = '\r\n'
$Replacement = ""
$NewXML = $XML -replace $Pattern, $Replacement
$NewXML | Set-Content -Path "Config.xml"
```

I'd expect the above to remove all line breaks in the file but it does nothing.

Comment: Powershell supports XML right out of the box, so why not edit the document as one edits an XML document?

Comment: @vonPryz I need the script to edit the xml, not manually edit it.

Comment: I don't think regex works for new lines as such I've found a workaround:   
    ```$XML = Get-Content "Config.xml"
$Pattern = ";;\t<!--Some description text here-->;;\t<Variable>.*?</Variable>;;"
$NewXML = [string]::join(";;",($xml.Split(" `r `n")))
$NewXML = $NewXML -replace $Pattern, ""
$NewXML = $NewXML -replace ";;"," `r `n"
$NewXML | Set-Content -Path "Config.xml"```

Apologies for formatting. Stackoverflow markdown guide states that adding two spaces after each line adds a linebreak but that's obviously false.

Comment: This question is relevant.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags


https://www.educba.com/powershell-xml/  - this is a good demo. I'd be looking at the xpath option

Comment: Edit the XML document as an _XML object_, not as _text_. Then you can use XMLDocument's `.RemoveChild()` and other methods that understand the XML structure.

Comment: Do you only want to remove the `<variable>` node when it's empty (eg. it doesn't have any child nodes)? Or do you want to remove all `<variable>` nodes and their descendants?